# Does using enum with associated value in Swift violate Liskov Substitution Principle?

Tags: swift, enums, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

```
enum WeatherType {
    case cloudy(coverage: Int)
    case sunny
    case windy
}
```

I just saw this in a Swift tutorial and I can't believe they allow you to do that. Now, whenever I switch on that enum, I gotta create a special case for `cloudy`!

Comment: As Vaca says below, while it is a very interesting discussion, it does not seem to relate specifically to the "Liskov Substitution Principle".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't "gotta" do anything. If you don't care what the coverage is, don't ask what the coverage is. If you don't care if it's cloudy, don't ask if it's cloudy. There is *nothing* special about the way you write a switch for a case that has an associated value.

Suppose we have this:

```
let weather = WeatherType.cloudy(coverage:1)
```

Then this is perfectly legal:

```
switch weather {
case .sunny:
    print("it is sunny")
default:
    print("I guess it's cloudy, or maybe windy")
}
```

And so is this!

```
switch weather {
case .cloudy:
    print("it is cloudy")
default:
    print("I guess it's sunny, or maybe windy")
}
```

Nor does any law require you to write a switch statement at all. If you simply want to know whether `weather` is `.cloudy`, just ask:

```
if case .cloudy = weather {
    print("yes it is cloudy")
} else {
    print("I guess it's sunny, or maybe windy")
}
```

And if you *do* happen to want to know what the `coverage` is, you *still* don't have to write a switch statement:

```
if case let .cloudy(cov) = weather {
    print("yes it is cloudy, in fact it is \(cov)")
} else {
    print("I guess it's sunny, or maybe windy")
}
```

What you *cannot* do is apply `==`. This won't compile:

```
if weather == .sunny { // error
```

To that extent, yes, an enum with an associated value behaves differently from an enum without an associated value (if that's what you're asking).

Comment: Thank you for this. I just find it weird that all members of an enum don't share the same set of parameters. It is of course not exactly LSP but it is a similar situation where interchangeable entities have different behaviors.

Comment: An enum is a type. A thing like `.cloudy` is not a "member"; it is an instance. Different instances can't have different data?

Comment: Yes, I think is does violate LSP,  different instances may have different data, but in the same format. Once you have enums with associated types you can't work with them the same way. It can generate messy code and many exception cases.

Answer (score 2):

> Now, whenever I switch on that `enum`, I gotta create a special case for `cloudy`!

That's not true, for several reasons:

- You can ignore `cloudy`, bunching it with `default`, and
- *Pattern matching* lets you read `coverage` property of `cloudy`, while treating `cloudy` itself as a single case.
- When you read the property `coverage` you have an option to ignore it, or to act on it.

Here are some examples:

```
switch weatherType {
case .Cloudy(_):
    print("It is cloudy. I ignore the coverage.")
...
}

switch weatherType {
case .Cloudy(let coverage):
    print("It is cloudy. Coverage is \(coverage).")
...
}

switch weatherType {
case .Cloudy(let coverage) where coverage > 80:
    print("It is very cloudy.")
case .Cloudy(let coverage) where coverage < 20:
    print("It is slightly cloudy.")
case .Cloudy(_):
    print("It is cloudy.")
...
}
```

Comment: I'd love to see a comment on an anonymous downvote here.

Comment: The anonymous down vote is one of my least favorite features of Stack Overflow.  How are you supposed to resolve the issue (if there is indeed one) without knowing why the person down voted?  I never down vote another person's answer on a question I have answered, but I do up vote others as I have just done here.

Comment: Thank you for this. I just find it weird that all members of an enum don't share the same set of parameters. It is of course not exactly LSP but it is a similar situation where interchangeable entities have different behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

The [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) has to do with subclassing.  Enums do not allow subclassing, so it isn't applicable here.

I'm not sure what your objection is about creating a special case for `cloudy`; you have to do that anyway in a `switch` if you want to specifically handle that case.  The extra syntax to grab the associated value is fairly straightforward.

```
let weather = WeatherType.cloudy(coverage: 17)

switch weather {
case .sunny:
    print("sunny")
case .windy:
    print("windy")
case .cloudy(let coverage):
    print("cloudy with coverage \(coverage)")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I just find it weird that all members of an enum don't share the same set of parameters. It is of course not exactly LSP but it is a similar situation where interchangeable entities have different behaviors.

Comment: I can understand that it seems a little weird, but it is very useful.  In fact, optionals are really just enums under the hood.  `Optional<Int>` has 2 enumeration values: `.none` which represents `nil` and `.some(Int)`.  So unwrapping an optional is really just extracting the associated value from the `.some` case.