# Swift enum evaluation

Tags: swift, enums, alamofire

Using Alamofire we're trying to determine if an error is a certain kind of error (response code 499) as represented by a "nested" [`AFError`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/AFError.swift) enum:

```
    if response.result.isFailure {
        if let aferror = error as? AFError {
            //THIS LINE FAILS 
            if (aferror == AFError.responseValidationFailed(reason: AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(code: 499))) {
               ....
            }
        }            
    }
```

But this results in the compiler error:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'AFError' operands

How can you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could trying extending `AFEError` to conform to `Equatable` in order to use `==`, but you are probably better off using `switch` and pattern matching:

```
switch aferror {
    case .responseValidationFailed(let reason) :
        switch reason {
            case AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(let code):
                if code == 499 { print("do something here") }
            default:
                print("You should handle all inner cases")
        {
    default:
        print("Handle other AFError cases")
}
```

This is the best syntax to ensure (and get the compiler to help you ensure) that all possible error cases and reasons are handled.  If you only want to address a single case, like in your example, you can use the newer `if case` syntax, like this:

```
if case .responseValidationFailed(let reason) = aferror, case AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(let code) = reason, code == 499 {
    print("Your code for this case here")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I point out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39944093/341994), you cannot, by default, apply the equality (`==`) operator between cases of an enum that as an associated value (on *any* of its cases); but there are many other ways to find out whether this is the desired case (and, if there is an associated value, to learn what the associated value may be).

Comment: You can apply `==` to enum cases that have an associated value if you make the enum type conform to `Equatable`.  You just don't get it for free.

Comment: Well put; I'll add that in. See also my bug report on this issue: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2900 — as Jordan Rose puts it, Swift fails to "synthesize Equatable", which is a more general complaint.

Comment: +1 for Swift automatically conforming / synthesizing enums with associated Equatable types to be Equatable themselves!  Maybe in Swift 4...